# Repeating letter with Logotech K380 bluetooth keyboard

Tags: wireless-networking, keyboard, bluetooth, wireless-keyboard, logitech-keyboard

I just bought a Logitech K380. After using it for about 4h, I've noted that it worked very well as long as there is no Apple Wireless keyboard around. There is a person in my room using apple wireless keyboard and when it turned on, my Logitech keyboard got stuck when typing. For example when I type "the little fox" it would become "thhhheee    litlllleeeeee fffffoxxxxx". The letters got repeating. But when he does not use Apple keyboard, everything seems to work fine with my Logitech keyboard. All I want to say is there any solution for this problem? Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the frequency/channel/band that the devices are operating on as it sounds like they are interfering.

Is he using an Apple AirPort?  If so, you can reboot that whilst your keyboard is on and it'll search for a channel that isn't being used.

Comment: I would like to know how to change the frequency of my bluetooth device. That's what I'm think of but I cannot find the solution on Google.

Comment: If you re-sync it with whatever device you are using, whilst the Apple keyboard is on and working, whilst pairing it should find a channel that isn't being used.